# Is it just a coincidence that Kleisli, ReaderT, and Reader are the same in Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz, reader-monad, kleisli

In Scalaz

- `Kleisli[F, A, B]` is a wrapper for `A => F[B]`.
- `ReaderT[F, A, B]` -- reader monad transformer -- is just an alias of `Kleisli[F, A, B]`.
- `Reader[A, B]` monad is a specialization of `ReaderT` with identity monad `Id`:
  `type Reader[A, B] = ReaderT[Id, A, B]`.

Is it just a coincidence or there are some *deeper* reasons that `Kleisli`, `ReaderT`, and `Reader` are isomorphic in Scalaz ?

Comment: Reader and ReaderT/Kleisli are not isomorphic (as you said, the former one is the specialization of the latter one).

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Thanks. I was wrong (won't update the question though).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can think of it as arriving at the same place by two different routes. On one side you start with the reader monad, which is simply a kind of wrapper for functions. Then you realize that you want to integrate this reader functionality into a larger monad with other "effects", so you create a `ReaderT` monad transformer. At that point it makes sense to implement your original `Reader[E, ?]` as `ReaderT[Id, E, ?]`.

From the other side, you want a type to represent Kleisli arrows (i.e. functions with a monadic return type). It turns out that this is the same thing as `ReaderT`, so you just make that an alias.

There's nothing terribly mysterious about the "it turns out" part. It's a little like if you started out with an `Addable` type class for number-like things, then decide to make it more generic, and eventually end up with a type class that just provides an associative "addition-like" operation. You've reinvented `Semigroup`! You may still want to keep the `Addable` name around, though, for historical or pedagogical reasons, or just for convenience.

That's all that's happening with `Reader` and `ReaderT`—you don't *need* these aliases, but they can be convenient, and may help improve the clarity of your code.

Comment: You can find an example on what Travis explained here: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Composing+monadic+functions.html