# Scalaz monad transformers. Applying f1:A => G[B], f2:B => G[C] function to F[G[A]] object

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, monad-transformers, function-composition

I have two (or more) functions defined as:

```
val functionM: String => Option[Int] = s => Some(s.length)
val functionM2: Int => Option[String] = i => Some(i.toString)
```

I also have some data defined as:

```
val data: List[Option[String]] = List(Option("abc"))
```

**My question is how to compose (in a nice way) the functions to get a result like:**

```
data.map(_.flatMap(functionM).flatMap(functionM2))
res0: List[Option[String]] = List(Some(3))
```

I don't like the syntax of the above function calls. If i have many places like this then the code is very unreadable.

I tried to play with OptionT scalaz monad transformer, but it still has nested maps and also generates nested Options like:

```
OptionT(data).map(a => functionM(a).map(functionM2)).run
res2: List[Option[Option[Option[String]]]] = List(Some(Some(Some(3))))
```

**What I want to achieve is something more or less like this:**

```
Something(data).map(functionM).map(functionM2)
```

or even better:

```
val functions = functionM andThenSomething functionM2
Something(data).map(functions)
```

**It would be nice if it could work with Try.** As I know scalaz doesn't have TryT monad transformer, so is there any way to nicely compose functions which operates on Try?

Comment: You can accomplish `val functions = functionM andThenSomething functionM2` with `Kleisli(functionM) >=> Kleisli(functionM2)` but I am not sure what do to next with this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Łukasz mentions, `Kleisli` seems most relevant here. Any time you have some functions of the shape `A => F[B]` and you want to compose them as if they were ordinary functions `A => B` (and you have a `flatMap` for `F`), you can represent the functions as Kleisli arrows:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val f1: Kleisli[Option, String, Int] = Kleisli(s => Some(s.length))
val f2: Kleisli[Option, Int, String] = Kleisli(i => Some(i.toString))
```

And then:

```
scala> f1.andThen(f2).run("test")
res0: Option[String] = Some(4)
```

If you're familiar with the idea of the reader monad, `Kleisli` is exactly the same thing as `ReaderT`—it's just a slightly more generic way of framing the idea (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29237252/334519) for more detail).

In this case it seems unlikely that monad transformers are what you're looking for, since you're not reaching all the way inside the `List[Option[A]]` to work directly with the `A`s—you're keeping the two levels distinct. Given the definitions of `f1` and `f2` above, I'd probably just write the following:

```
scala> val data: List[Option[String]] = List(Option("abc"))
data: List[Option[String]] = List(Some(abc))

scala> data.map(_.flatMap(f1.andThen(f2)))
res1: List[Option[String]] = List(Some(3))
```

Lastly, just because Scalaz doesn't provide a `Monad` (or `Bind`, which is what you'd need here) instance for `Try`, that doesn't mean you can't write your own. For example:

```
import scala.util.{ Success, Try }

implicit val bindTry: Bind[Try] = new Bind[Try] {
  def map[A, B](fa: Try[A])(f: A => B): Try[B] = fa.map(f)
  def bind[A, B](fa: Try[A])(f: A => Try[B]): Try[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
}

val f1: Kleisli[Try, String, Int] = Kleisli(s => Success(s.length))
val f2: Kleisli[Try, Int, String] = Kleisli(i => Success(i.toString))
```

And then:

```
scala> val data: List[Try[String]] = List(Try("abc"))
data: List[scala.util.Try[String]] = List(Success(abc))

scala> data.map(_.flatMap(f1.andThen(f2)))
res5: List[scala.util.Try[String]] = List(Success(3))
```

Some people have some concerns about the lawfulness of a `Functor` or `Monad` or `Bind` instance like this for `Try` in the presence of exceptions, and these people tend to be loud people, but I find it hard to care (in my view there are [better reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31405256/334519) to avoid `Try` altogether).

Comment: There is an improvement for using Kleisli. If we really want to avoid using nested map we can use OptionT transformer.

 import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val f1: Kleisli[Option, String, Int] = Kleisli(s => Some(s.length))
val f2: Kleisli[Option, Int, String] = Kleisli(i => Some(i.toString))
val f3: Kleisli[Option, String, String] = Kleisli(s => Some(s + " hello"))

val functions: Kleisli[Option, String, String] = f1 andThen f2 andThen f3

val data: List[Option[String]] = List(Option("abc"))

OptionT.optionT(data).map(functions).run.flatten